# Intuitive explanation of precipitation amount

Tags: meteorology, measurements, precipitation, weather-forecasting

I'm trying to learn how to make sense of numbers in a forecast. I can interpret temperature and wind speed, but I don't know what to make of rainfall. What does it mean, for a human, that there will be (for example) 0.5mm precipitation? Is it a lot or not? Is there a reference online describing precipitation amounts in everyday terms? I've been looking for something like that, but found nothing, only formal definitions of measurement.